# GROUP BY and COUNT in Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I need to get a top-level count for the subquery, the query is filled with some mock values, actually I want to get a count of the id's that's in the IN operation, in this example it would be 2. Group by is required by the postgre. Also, I'm using knex, on a case, if it would be helpful

```
select "uid", count(uid)
from "table"
where ("table"."field" not in ('v1', 'v2'))
  and "table"."uid" in ('1', '2')
group by "table"."uid"
order by "table"."createdAt" desc
```

Current output is

```
[
  {
    "uid": "1",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "uid": "2",
    "count": 1
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a top-level count of your query you can use the following syntax:

```
select count(*) from ( %YOURQUERY% ) q;
```

Note that you always need an alias (`q` in this case) for an inner query. Also note that in the inner query the `ORDER BY` clause is avoidable.

As a side note, to answer your specific problem, it's enough for you to run the following:

```
select count(*) from table where uid in ('1', '2');
```